# How to create lightning page for a custom object?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps

I'm new to Salesforce development and currently learning about lightning web components.

Currently I'm just trying to build a lightning page which look like below for my custom object.

[image]

But It seems to get the drop down like its shown in the image you need to create a Record Page, but if we created a record page the custom object is not being listed in the list of objects for List View component. Can someone help me create a similar page for my custom component where I have to have both list view as well as the drop down in the tab.

Questions:

1) What type of page(App Page, Home Page,Record Page) I have to use to get similar functionality as Leads page?

2) How to add the List View for my custom object?

For the first question i most probably think it is record page, but record page offers detail view not the list view. If i dragged list view component my custom object is not shown in the object list

Comment: What do you mean by saying if we created a record page the custom object is not being listed in the list of objects for List View component. ?

Comment: When we create an app page with the custom object and inside app builder when we add a list view and searched for the custom object in the drop down the custom objects are not being listed

Answer (score 1):

You should know these points:-

1. If you have created any custom object, and then the tab for it using tab wizard, You will automatically get the list view and the drop down as you are referring to in the question.
2. List View component for app page can be used for custom object as well. But you don't need it.

> Note:- If you have not created tab for an object, it will not come for
>   list view in app page.

So, You just need to create a tab for your custom object and you will automatically get the drop down and list view

Learn here to create tab for an object:- [Create a tab for custom object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_custom_object_tabs.htm&type=5)

Comment: Is it possible to edit the page contents if i created a tab for an object for example i would want to have additional components along with that list view

Comment: A huge THANK YOU! I was stuck on this for 2 days.